# Difference between Task and TaskFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, comparison, task, taskfactory

Can any one explain the difference between  `Task and Task Factory`?

**task :**

```
 public Task(Func<TResult> function);
```

**Task Factory:**

```
public static TaskFactory<TResult> Factory { get; }
```

Please explain with uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put Task.Run is a simplified version of TaskFactory and does exactly the same. With taskfactory you just have some more options(e.g. TaskCreationOptions)